# How do you allow user control over turtle and once hovering over desired spot to execute a specific function for those coordinates

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am creating a custom car game for a school project and would like to know how to allow the user to navigate the turtle to the color they wish to use and then use that color after hitting enter. I am coding this using python turtle and am thinking I need to use the keyboard listen function but do not know how.
[Here is what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIdNO.png)

```
# David, Wilson

# January 29th, 2021

# Custom Car Designer Game

import turtle


sc = turtle.Screen()

sc.setup(1400, 700)


graphic = turtle.Turtle()



# Turtle window title

usersName = turtle.textinput("Users Name", "Please enter your name to get started:")

turtle.title(" " + usersName + "'s Custom Car Simulator")


graphic.speed("fastest")


# The Sky

graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(0, 200)

graphic.pendown()

graphic.color("SkyBlue")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.forward(700)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(200)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(1400)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(200)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(700)

graphic.end_fill()


# The Sun

graphic.color("yellow")

graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(-640, 240)

graphic.pendown()

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.circle(70)

graphic.end_fill()


# The Grass

graphic.color("LimeGreen")

graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(0, 200)

graphic.pendown()

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.forward(700)

graphic.right(90)

graphic.forward(250)

graphic.right(90)

graphic.forward(1400)

graphic.right(90)

graphic.forward(250)

graphic.right(90)

graphic.forward(700)

graphic.end_fill()



def drawGreen4Tree():

# tree stem

turtle.right(180)

turtle.speed(100)

turtle.pensize(20)

turtle.color("Brown")

turtle.right(180)

turtle.right(90)

turtle.forward(75)

# tree foliage

turtle.pensize(1)

turtle.left(90)

turtle.forward(10)

turtle.left(90)

turtle.forward(75)

turtle.left(90)

turtle.color("green4")

turtle.begin_fill()

turtle.forward(100)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(100)

turtle.left(150)

turtle.forward(75)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(75)

turtle.left(150)

turtle.forward(50)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(50)

turtle.left(150)

turtle.forward(25)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(50)

turtle.right(60)

turtle.forward(50)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(25)

turtle.left(150)

turtle.forward(50)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(50)

turtle.left(150)

turtle.forward(75)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(75)

turtle.left(150)

turtle.forward(100)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(100)

turtle.end_fill()



def drawChartReuseTree1():

# tree stem

turtle.right(180)

turtle.speed(100)

turtle.pensize(10)

turtle.color("Brown")

turtle.right(180)

turtle.right(90)

turtle.forward(37.5)

# tree foliage

turtle.pensize(1)

turtle.left(90)

turtle.forward(5)

turtle.left(90)

turtle.forward(37.5)

turtle.left(90)

turtle.color("chartreuse")

turtle.begin_fill()

turtle.forward(50)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(50)

turtle.left(150)

turtle.forward(37.5)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(37.5)

turtle.left(150)

turtle.forward(25)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(25)

turtle.left(150)

turtle.forward(12.5)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(25)

turtle.right(60)

turtle.forward(12.5)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(12.5)

turtle.left(150)

turtle.forward(25)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(25)

turtle.left(150)

turtle.forward(37.5)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(37.5)

turtle.left(150)

turtle.forward(50)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(50)

turtle.end_fill()



def drawDarkOliveTree2():

# tree stem

turtle.right(180)

turtle.speed(100)

turtle.pensize(10)

turtle.color("Brown")

turtle.right(180)

turtle.right(90)

turtle.forward(37.5)

# tree foliage

turtle.pensize(1)

turtle.left(90)

turtle.forward(5)

turtle.left(90)

turtle.forward(37.5)

turtle.left(90)

turtle.color("Dark Olive Green")

turtle.begin_fill()

turtle.forward(50)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(50)

turtle.left(150)

turtle.forward(37.5)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(37.5)

turtle.left(150)

turtle.forward(25)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(25)

turtle.left(150)

turtle.forward(12.5)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(25)

turtle.right(60)

turtle.forward(12.5)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(12.5)

turtle.left(150)

turtle.forward(25)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(25)

turtle.left(150)

turtle.forward(37.5)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(37.5)

turtle.left(150)

turtle.forward(50)

turtle.right(150)

turtle.forward(50)

turtle.end_fill()



# The Road

graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(0, -50)

graphic.pendown()

graphic.color("Black")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.forward(700)

graphic.right(90)

graphic.forward(200)

graphic.right(90)

graphic.forward(1400)

graphic.right(90)

graphic.forward(200)

graphic.right(90)

graphic.forward(700)

graphic.end_fill()


line1 = turtle.Turtle()

line2 = turtle.Turtle()


# White Lines

line1.penup()

line1.setpos(0, -150)

line1.pendown()

line1.pensize(10)

for i in range(10):

line1.color("white")

line1.forward(35)

line1.color("Black")

line1.forward(35)

line2.penup()

line2.setpos(0, -150)

line2.pendown()

line2.left(180)

line2.pensize(10)

for i in range(10):

line2.color("Black")

line2.forward(35)

line2.color("White")

line2.forward(35)


# The Shed

graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(0, -50)

graphic.pendown()

graphic.color("Grey")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.forward(150)

graphic.right(180)

graphic.forward(300)

graphic.right(90)

graphic.forward(150)

graphic.right(90)


graphic.forward(300)

graphic.right(90)

graphic.forward(150)

graphic.end_fill()

# The Shed Roof

graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(-150, 100)

graphic.pendown()

graphic.color("BurlyWood")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.left(120)

graphic.forward(125)

graphic.right(30)

graphic.forward(85)

graphic.right(30)

graphic.forward(125)

graphic.end_fill()

# The Sign on the Roof

graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(-30, 135)

graphic.pendown()

graphic.color("Black")

graphic.write(" " + usersName + "'s ", font=("Times New Roman", 18, "normal"))

graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(-60, 105)

graphic.pendown()

graphic.write("Kustom Kars", font=("Times New Roman", 18, "normal"))

# The flags on the building

graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(-150, 100)

graphic.pendown()

graphic.color("red")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.right(270)

graphic.left(240)

graphic.forward(25)

graphic.left(120)

graphic.forward(25)

graphic.end_fill()

for i in range(3):

graphic.color("White")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.left(240)

graphic.forward(25)

graphic.left(120)

graphic.forward(25)

graphic.end_fill()

graphic.color("blue")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.left(240)

graphic.forward(25)

graphic.left(120)

graphic.forward(25)

graphic.end_fill()

graphic.color("red")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.left(240)

graphic.forward(25)

graphic.left(120)

graphic.forward(25)

graphic.end_fill()

graphic.color("White")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.left(240)

graphic.forward(25)

graphic.left(120)

graphic.forward(25)

graphic.end_fill()

graphic.color("blue")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.left(240)

graphic.forward(25)

graphic.left(120)

graphic.forward(25)

graphic.end_fill()

# The Garage Door

graphic.color("Gainsboro")

graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(-140, -50)

graphic.pendown()

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.left(30)

graphic.forward(125)

graphic.right(90)

graphic.forward(200)

graphic.right(90)

graphic.forward(125)

graphic.end_fill()

# The Windows on the Garage Door

graphic.color("SlateGray")

graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(-130, 50)

graphic.pendown()

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.forward(20)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(30)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(20)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(30)

graphic.end_fill()


graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(-85, 50)

graphic.pendown()

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(20)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(30)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(20)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(30)

graphic.end_fill()


graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(-40, 50)

graphic.pendown()

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(20)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(30)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(20)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(30)

graphic.end_fill()


graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(5, 50)

graphic.pendown()

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(20)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(30)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(20)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(30)

graphic.end_fill()


# The other garage door

graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(85, -50)

graphic.pendown()

graphic.color("Gainsboro")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.right(90)

graphic.forward(100)

graphic.right(90)

graphic.forward(45)

graphic.right(90)

graphic.forward(100)

graphic.end_fill()

# The door knob

graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(115, -10)

graphic.pendown()

graphic.color("SlateGray")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.circle(5)

graphic.end_fill()

graphic.pendown()


# The Checkered Flag


graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(-415, -50)

graphic.pendown()

graphic.color("grey")

graphic.pensize(10)

graphic.right(180)

graphic.forward(125)

graphic.pensize(1)

graphic.right(90)

print(graphic.pos())

for i in range(5):

graphic.color("white")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.end_fill()


graphic.color("Black")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.end_fill()


graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(-415, 65)

graphic.pendown()

for i in range(5):

graphic.color("Black")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.end_fill()


graphic.color("White")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.end_fill()


graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(-415, 55)

graphic.pendown()


for i in range(5):

graphic.color("White")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.end_fill()


graphic.color("Black")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.end_fill()


graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(-415, 45)

graphic.pendown()


for i in range(5):

graphic.color("Black")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.end_fill()


graphic.color("White")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.end_fill()


graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(-415, 35)

graphic.pendown()


for i in range(5):

graphic.color("White")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.end_fill()


graphic.color("Black")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(10)

graphic.end_fill()


turtle.textinput("Welcome", "Greetings " + usersName + " and welcome to your very own custom car simulator in this "

"program you will be able to design your own car. Including "

"tire sizes and custom colors of your pick for the whole car. "

"Are you ready to get started? Please hit enter to continue.")


turtleMechanic = turtle.Turtle()


turtleMechanic.penup()

turtleMechanic.setpos(300, 150)

turtleMechanic.pendown()


turtleMechanic.right(90)

turtleMechanic.shape("turtle")

turtleMechanic.shapesize(5)

turtleMechanic.color("SeaGreen")


turtle.textinput("Turtle", "Hello if you notice the giant turtle on your screen I will be the one to help you design "

"your car. Well, actually the smaller version of me will be helping you. Please hit enter "

"to continue.")



def drawCar(c):

graphic.shape("turtle")

graphic.width(6)

graphic.speed(1)


graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(-175.00, -175.00)

graphic.pendown()

graphic.color("Black")

graphic.forward(26)

graphic.color("White")

graphic.forward(100)

graphic.color("black")

graphic.forward(52)

graphic.color("White")

graphic.forward(25)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(50)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(50)

graphic.right(60)

graphic.forward(50)

graphic.left(60)

graphic.forward(100)

graphic.left(60)

graphic.forward(50)

graphic.left(120)

graphic.forward(75)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(44)

graphic.backward(44)

graphic.right(90)

graphic.forward(75)

graphic.backward(200)

graphic.right(90)

graphic.forward(50)

graphic.left(90)

graphic.forward(15)

graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(-175, -200)

graphic.pendown()

graphic.color("white")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.circle(25)

graphic.end_fill()


graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(-25, -200)

graphic.pendown()

graphic.color("white")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.circle(25)

graphic.end_fill()


graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(-175, -175)

graphic.pendown()

graphic.color("white")

graphic.forward(25)

for i in range(10): # to draw lines in circle

graphic.color("black")

graphic.penup()

graphic.goto(-25, -175)

graphic.pendown()

graphic.left(36)

graphic.forward(25)

graphic.backward(25)


for i in range(10): # to draw lines in circle

graphic.color("Black")

graphic.penup()

graphic.goto(-175, -175)

graphic.pendown()

graphic.left(36)

graphic.forward(25)

graphic.backward(25)



drawCar(graphic)



graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(-600, -350)

graphic.penup()

graphic.color("Blue")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.circle(50)

graphic.end_fill()


graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(-400, -350)

graphic.penup()

graphic.color("Red")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.circle(50)

graphic.end_fill()


graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(-200, -350)

graphic.penup()

graphic.color("Yellow")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.circle(50)

graphic.end_fill()


graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(0, -350)

graphic.penup()

graphic.color("Orange")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.circle(50)

graphic.end_fill()


graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(200, -350)

graphic.penup()

graphic.color("Green")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.circle(50)

graphic.end_fill()


graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(400, -350)

graphic.penup()

graphic.color("Navajo White")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.circle(50)

graphic.end_fill()


graphic.penup()

graphic.setpos(600, -350)

graphic.penup()

graphic.color("Magenta")

graphic.begin_fill()

graphic.circle(50)

graphic.end_fill()



turtle.done()
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you have so far?

Comment: Check out this tutorial: https://www.techwithtim.net/tutorials/python-module-walk-throughs/turtle-module/key-presses-events/

Comment: Sorry it took me a while but I was able to share my code

Comment: @DavidWilson : It would be helpful if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  We can then solve your problem faster, because then there would be less code.